# Is it good practice to pass the negation of value to ngIf angular directive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, frontend

I want your opinion.
Is it good practice to pass the negation of value to ngIf angular directive ?
e.g.

```
<table *ngIf="!isLoading else loaderTemplate">
  ... 
</table>

<ng-template #loaderTemplate>
    <div>Loading...</div>
</ng-template>
```

or we should not use the negation like...

```
 <div *ngIf="isLoading else dataTemplate">
    Loading...
 </div>

 <ng-template #dataTemplate>
   <table> .... </table> 
 </ng-template>
```

Which approch should we follow in Angular apps?

Comment: If it works, the use it. ;)

Comment: Doesn’t matter.

Comment: Some authors say that it's **always** better use variables in "positive mode" (It's more easy understand it). e.g., better use a variable "yetLoaded" and use *ngIf="yetLoaded" than use a variable isLoading and use *ngIf="!isLoading", but you ask about opinion, so always the variable have no a negative expression, (never use a variable like "notIsLoading" and use *ngIf="!notIsLoading") for me is a good approach

Comment: It flows better and is more readable when you don't use negation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading else dataTemplate">
   Loading...
</div>

<ng-template #dataTemplate>
  <table> .... </table> 
</ng-template>
```

You may use both, but always better to use "positive mode", it is easy to understand